# Kubernetes Cluster Initialization Fails with Kubeadm and CRI-O on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kubernetes, containers, kubeadm

I am setting up a Kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu Server LTS 22.04 using Vagrant, with Kubernetes version 1.28.7 and CRI-O 1.28.2 as the container runtime. I'm encountering an issue when initializing the cluster with the `kubeadm init` command. Despite the absence of errors in both kubelet and CRI-O service logs, the initialization fails.

The command used is:

`sudo kubeadm init --config /etc/kubernetes/kubeadm-config.yaml --v=5`

The process fails at the phase upload-config/kubelet with an error message indicating that the node "master" is not found. Here are relevant excerpts from the command output:

`[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed. nodes "master" not found Error writing Crisocket information for the control-plane node`

I checked the running containers in CRI-O, and all necessary Kubernetes components seem to be running correctly:

`root@master:~# crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause`

This is the kubeadm-config.yaml file used in the init command:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: ClusterConfiguration
clusterName: kubernetes
kubernetesVersion: v1.28.7
networking:
  podSubnet: 172.16.1.0/16
  serviceSubnet: 172.17.1.0/18
controlPlaneEndpoint: 10.0.0.101:6443
apiServer:
  certSANs:
    - 10.0.0.101
---
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: InitConfiguration
bootstrapTokens:
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
  token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef
  ttl: 24h0m0s
  usages:
  - signing
  - authentication
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 10.0.0.101
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  name: master
  taints: null
---
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: KubeletConfiguration
cgroupDriver: systemd
...
```

I also confirmed that "master" is the hostname of the node and checked the /etc/crictl.yaml configuration:

`runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/crio/crio.sock timeout: 10 debug: false`

I have attempted using Kubernetes 1.29.2 and switching the container runtime to containerd without success. All services are up and running, and the Kubernetes API on 10.0.0.101:6443 is reachable. There are no errors in the kubeadm init preflight.

Versions:

Kubernetes: 1.28.7
CRI-O: 1.28.2
Ubuntu: 22.04
Vagrant: 2.4.1
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.